# Proper procedure for logit regression

Tags: logistic, categorical-data, aic

The data I've been given has a mass of two level factor variables, roughly 10. However, all of these variables are mutually exclusive. The online form is recording whether you checked a box or not, but you can only check one box at most. I've already cleaned up the data to put any case of all FALSE to being "Not specified" = TRUE.

Due to the excessive number of variables, I just shoved it into the logit as is. However, my boss expanded his requests, so I had to spend time recoding all 10 T/F variables into a single factor with 10 levels.

My question stems from a difference in AIC between the two models. I've selected the model from each form of the dataframe. However, the model that uses 10 2-level variables has a much lower AIC than the model that has a single 10 level variable.

I know I kind of broke the rules when it comes to independent variables for logit regression, so I'm wondering if I should throw out the excessively large model for improper application or keep it for excessively lower AIC (about -70 from the condensed model).

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: This doesn't make sense as stated because most software automatically split a factor into its constituent dummies. This makes me think there is a coding error rather than a statistical issue. Can you produce some code and output or attempt to replicate the scenario with a toy dataset?

Comment: The 10 2-level factors are split into TRUE/FALSE as you say, and regression compares each log-odds of the TRUE effect in reference to the FALSE effect like one would expect. There is no error displayed from the regression. My issue is since only 1 of these 10 variables can be true at a time, they are not independent. I originally ignored this problem since they aren't just dependent but mutually exclusive. Therefore (in my mind) they acted like a single factor that is still independent from the other variables I'm using. It's the massive difference in AIC that has me questioning the reasoning.

Comment: By error I didn't mean a failure of the regression to run, I meant a mistake in your codd. The massive difference in AIC is indicative of a potential error in your coding because theoretically the AIC should be exactly the same regardless of how you've coded it. We can't answer the statistical question, which is on the surface implausible, without knowing what coding choices you made that led to you to believe you have a statistics question when in reality this might be just a coding error.